# How to import a database located at a different path in Neo4J?

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am new to Neo4j and wondering how to import a stand alone database located at different path in Neo4j.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to copy your database inside `$NEO4J_HOME/data/databases` directory of your database.

Rename your database name to `graph.db` because By default `graph.db` is the active database in Neo4j.

If your database name is different from `graph.db`, You need to change `neo4j.conf` file. You can uncomment and change the active database name on the following line.

```
#dbms.active_database=graph.db
```

like

```
dbms.active_database=twitter-trolls.db
```

**If you are using Neo4j desktop.**
You can change these setting under settings tab as shown in the following image. You can find `$NEO4J_HOME` by clicking the `Open Folder` button.
[image]

Comment: You can also change the dbms.directories.data property to point to database location but it's somewhat confusing.

Comment: Thank you Raj, your approach worked very well on my end. I am pretty sure your answer will help a lot of developers. I appreciate it!